# Assign const 1D array from const 2D array row inside a header file c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants

I have searched in a few places already for a solution to this problem and have come up short. Essentially what I am looking to do is to assign a const 1D array from one of the rows of a const 2d array and specifically to do it in a header file.

Say I have

```
const int Arr1[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

and I want to initialize an array (within a header file) from this array. I know normally I could do:

```
const int *Arr2 = Arr1[1];
```

or

```
const int *Arr2 = Arr1[0];
```

but doing so in a header file gives multiple definition errors. So my question is if there is a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *multiple definition errors* don't have anything to do with your assignment.

Just say in your header

```
 extern const int *Arr2;
```

and initialize it in a separate translation unit:

```
 const int Arr1[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
 const int *Arr2 = Arr1[1];
```

---

Maybe selectively from preprocessor directives:

```
 const int Arr1[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
 #ifdef ZERO_PATH
 const int *Arr2 = Arr1[0];
                     // ^ ZERO_PATH
 #else
 const int *Arr2 = Arr1[1];
 #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
const int *Arr2 = Arr1[1];
```

initializes a pointer, not an array.  Arrays and pointers are different. It's not clear from your post whether you're content with using a pointer, but if so then you either need to setup as in πάντα ῥεῖ's answer; or give `Arr2` internal linkage:

```
const int *const Arr2 = Arr1[1];    // if you do not plan to change Arr2
static const int *Arr2 = Arr1[1];   // if you do
```

---

To actually use an array you can write:

```
const int Arr2[3] = { Arr1[1][0], Arr1[1][1], Arr1[1][2] };
```

There's no way to use a whole C-style array as initializer for another array of the same type. But if you use C++-style arrays you can do that:

```
const array<array<int, 3>, 2> Arr1 = {{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6} }};

const array<int, 3> Arr2 = Arr1[0];
```